# Mass convert Vue.js templates into Pug format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, pug

Is there a way to mass convert existing Vue.js templates (single file components) into Pug (Jade)?

Something similar to the erb2slim gem for rails.

I find Pug much more legible and its impractical to rewrite an existing open source project.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few Jade converters like [Html2Jade](http://html2jade.org/) as you're just converting the html. It even appears to keep vue directives including shorthand `:bind` and `@on`.

The downside is that it's a manual converter so you will have to paste in each component separately.

Comment: The website is actually runnable locally, just clone https://github.com/dylankbuckley/html2pug and `npm install && npm start` to do so. Surely one can go a bit further and use code under the hood to do the conversion at scale automatically.